# Configuration Mandril Heroku Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mandrill

I have been trying for a long time to configure a mail sender for heroku, 
It was imposible with sendgrid, now im trying with Mandril. 
It says i have to put this code, but i don't know where, any sugestion?

```
require 'mandrill'
m = Mandrill::API.new # All official Mandrill API clients will automatically pull your API key from the environment
rendered = m.templates.render 'MyTemplate', [{:name => 'main', :content => 'The main content block'}]
puts rendered['html'] # print out the rendered HTML
```

This is my logs:

```
2015-06-17T01:01:50.949397+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-06-17T01:01:50.949399+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-06-17T01:01:50.949400+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-17T01:01:50.949402+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-17T01:01:50.957251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/password"
```

enviroment/production.rb

```
}

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :port =>           '587',
    :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    :user_name =>      ENV['mandrilusername'],
    :password =>       ENV['mandrilpass'],
    :domain =>         'heroku.com',
    :authentication => :plain
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

end
```

Any erros here

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I configure ActionMailer to send through Mandrill on Heroku.  Stick this in your config/environments/production.rb (or the appropriate environment for your Heroku instance):

```
# Send emails through Mandrill
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'example.com',
  user_name: ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['MANDRILL_PASSWORD']
}
```

Then set the two environment variables from the command line:

```
heroku config:set MANDRILL_USERNAME=myusername
heroku config:set MANDRILL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```